Is generic type hinting in C is possible?
Polymorphism in C is a big pain. For obvious reasons, generalized C code will consist of structures containing void* pointers and functions returning such structures (or pointers to them, or exactly the same void* pointers).
Next, you look at the library documentation and learn how you should cast types for further work.
The situation could be saved by some Python-style type-hinting. None of changes and guarantees at runtime, but with hints in a smart enough IDE and warnings at compile time if you cast pointers in some unexpected way. So you always know without documentation and looking into the source code where the pointer is pointing.
typedef void* gpointer;

typedef struct _GPtrArray;

__attribute__(generic_struct, TDATA)
struct _GPtrArray
   {  
      gpointer *pdata; __attribute__(cast_field, TDATA)
      guint    len;
   };

...

__attribute__(cast_return, *InstalledRef)
GPtrArray*
function_list_installed_refs(...args) 
   { 
      ... 
   }

__attribute__(cast_return, *RecentlyDeletedRef)
GPtrArray*
function_list_recently_deleted_refs(...args)
   { 
      ... 
   }

int 
calculate_something(
   GPtrArray *installed __attribute__(cast_arg, *InstalledRef)
) 
   { 
      ... 
   }

...

g_autoptr(GPtrArray) installed = function_list_installed_refs(...);
for (guint i = 0; i < apps->len; i++)
    {
      // warnings
      // 1.    RecentlyDeletedRef *app = g_ptr_array_index (apps, i);
      // 2.    ... (RecentlyDeletedRef*)g_ptr_array_index (apps, i) ...
      // 3.    void *app = g_ptr_array_index (apps, i);
      // 4.    int value = calculate_something(app);
               
      // okays 
      // 1.    InstalledRef *app = g_ptr_array_index (apps, i);
      // 2.    (InstalledRef*)g_ptr_array_index (apps, i)
      // 3.    int value = calculate_something(app);
    }

Are there any C compiler extensions that provide this capability? Or maybe there are complexities that make this approach impossible or impractical?
It seems to me that it should be very convenient for developers and very useful for static analysis, but I cannot find any info on the web.
OF COURSE, you can make a macro definition to create generic data structures, but it has known drawbacks (and it's ugly) (and you'll burn in hell of non-understandable compile errors if something went wrong).

With enough preprocessing, smart compilers and IDEs you can turn C into another language entirely. But why would you? You'd end up with C-but-you-can't-really-use-it-with-another-IDE at which point you might as well switch to another language that supports features like that out of the box.

Polymorphism is normally implemented with opaque types where the first member of the child is the parent. And the parent share a header with the inherited child, containing information about its "protected" members. Why you would use void pointers anywhere, I have no idea. So this sounds like an "XY question" - implement polymorphism properly instead of this.

You are trying to use the wrong language for the job.  When it gets unreadable and inscrutable, it is time to switch to a language that supports the coding techniques you want to use.

@JoachimSauer Why do you talk about IDEs? I talk about some compiler extensions or attributes for compile-time checks. Possibility of type hints in IDE is just a one possible optional indirect benefit

@Lundin I understand this. And anyway there's a lot of cases where void* pointers are used. My example is not abstract, it is literally what the glib source code consists of.

Personally, I'd be happy if, in addition to notes in the documentation like “Returns a GPtrArray of FlatpakInstalledRef instances.”, I had at least some hints in the IDE or warnings from compiler at compile time if I'm doing something wrong

It's not a "void* pointers pros and cons" question. That's how things work in a lot of projects, I want to understand is there a way to make it less painful

@JoachimSauer In the same way you can say this about many other compiler extensions like the GNU cleanup attribute. Regardless of your or mine opinion, it exists and is used widely and it has application area

Well there's good programming practices and there's *nix open source goo practices... Most projects like that are very old and suffer from extreme code rot, having been messed around with endlessly and inconsistently by diverse people over the years. Meaning these code bases are excellent to look at for inspiration regarding how to not write code.

@Lundin That's all clear and doesn't need any clarification. Again, the question is not how to code in proper way, but how to make working with such projects less disgusting without refactoring and rewriting everything to fit good practices. how many lines of code are there? You can't just go and rewrite and refactor everything, it's too big. There has to be some intermediate compromise solution as well. That's what I ask.

@Lundin -- "...and there's *nix open source goo practices...." Perhaps "goo" was a Freudian slip?

@witaway -- "...the question is not how to code in proper way, but how to make working with such projects less disgusting...." It wasn't clear to me from your posted question that you are asking about how to work with existing code bases using void * rather than asking about implementing polymorphism yourself. A more specific example of what you are talking about might help (or better, a [mcve]).

@adabsurdum Have you seen the code of the Linux kernal or glibc?
